# Fill div with image (not stretch it) using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

How can I accomplish this behaviour http://jsfiddle.net/salman/2gWVQ/ but instead of using CSS I would like to use JavaScript.

```
<div class="square"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x200/FC0/000000" class="wide">
</div>
<br>
<div class="square"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x400/FC0/000000" class="tall">
</div>

.square {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    /* center align trick */
    line-height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}

.square img {
    /* center align trick */
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.square .wide {
    width: 150px;
}
.square .tall {
    height: 150px;
}
```

According to the link I would like the image to adjust to the width/height and keep ratio, and both image and div dimensions are variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
image.onload = function(){
    var ratioWidth = div.width / image.width;
    var ratioHeight = div.height / image.height;

    if (ratioWidth < ratioHeight) {
      image.width = div.width;
      image.style.top = -((image.height - div.height) / 2) + "px";
    } else {
      image.height = div.height;
      image.style.left = -((image.width - div.width) / 2) + "px";
    }
  };
```